# Writing multi-indexed data to an excel file with Python/Pandas

Tags: python, excel, pandas, multi-index, xlwt

I want to create an Excel spreadsheet and insert equal number of rows for each of variable. The ideal result shall looked like Columns A & B in the picture.

What I can do so far is only to insert for 1 name (Columns D & E), and have no idea do the proper enumeration for the rest.

[image: name and food]

This is what I have:

```
import xlwt, xlrd
import os

current_file = xlwt.Workbook()
write_table = current_file.add_sheet('Sheet1')

name_list = ["Jack", "David", "Andy"]
food_list = ["Ice-cream", "Mango", "Apple", "Cake"]

total_rows = len(name_list) * len(food_list)   # how to use it?

write_table.write(0, 0, "Jack")

for row, food in enumerate(food_list):
    write_table.write(row, 1, food)

current_file.save("c:\\name_food.xls")
```

How can I do it for all? Thank you.

Comment: Why is this tagged pandas? You're not even importing it.

Comment: @COLDSPEED, I imagine Pandas can do magic here. :)

Comment: There's no point in asking for a pandas solution unless you have pandas and are seriously considering using the solution someone provides you. If you are then that's fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
import xlwt, xlrd
import os

current_file = xlwt.Workbook()
write_table = current_file.add_sheet('Sheet1')

name_list = ["Jack", "David", "Andy"]
food_list = ["Ice-cream", "Mango", "Apple", "Cake"]

for i, name in enumerate(name_list):
    write_table.write(i * len(food_list), 0, name_list[i])

    for row, food in enumerate(food_list):
        write_table.write(i * len(food_list) + row, 1, food)

current_file.save("c:\\name_food.xls")
```

The important part is

```
write_table.write(i * len(food_list), 0, name_list[i])
```

where You say that name should be written in rows 0, 4, 8, 12...

Also, part

```
write_table.write(i * len(food_list) + row, 1, food)
```

writes food to corresponding section increased by row number.

Comment: Marvelous! That’s amazing thinking. Thank you for the help. btw, if you mind I choose COOLSPEED's for the answer?

Comment: generous! it's yours.

Answer (score 4):

You can create `DataFrame` by [`numpy.tile`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.tile.html) and [`numpy.repeat`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.repeat.html) and then remove duplicated in `a` column:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': np.repeat(name_list, len(food_list)),
                   'b': np.tile(food_list, len(name_list))})

df['a'] = np.where(df['a'].duplicated(), '', df['a'])
print (df)
        a          b
0    Jack  Ice-cream
1              Mango
2              Apple
3               Cake
4   David  Ice-cream
5              Mango
6              Apple
7               Cake
8    Andy  Ice-cream
9              Mango
10             Apple
11              Cake
```

Another solution with list comprehension:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [y for x in name_list for y in [x] + [''] * (len(food_list)-1)],
                   'b': food_list * len(name_list)})
print (df)
        a          b
0    Jack  Ice-cream
1              Mango
2              Apple
3               Cake
4   David  Ice-cream
5              Mango
6              Apple
7               Cake
8    Andy  Ice-cream
9              Mango
10             Apple
11              Cake
```

And last write [`to_excel`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html):

```
df.to_excel('c:\\name_food.xls', index=False, header=False)
```

Comment: thank you! This’s absolutely a super bonus in learning. Would you mind I choose the solution used xlrd the Answer?

Comment: It is up to you. ;) Every answerer is happy if his answer is accepted ;)